# python: how to check the use of an external program

Tags: python

In Python, how do you check that an external program is running? I'd like to track my use of some programs, so I can see the amount of time I've spent with them. For example, if I launch my program , I want to be able to see if Chrome has already been launched, and if so, start a timer which would end when I exit Chrome.
Ive seen that then subprocess module can launch external programs, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `psutil`

It is great to get information on the system (CPU / RAM / HD / ...)

And in your case, processes : https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#processes

Comment: thank you for your answer. Ive checked your link, and I see that we can easily check if the app has been launched. However, how do I get the time "value" (amount of time since the process was opened). Thanks in advance

Comment: you can get this with psutil, just RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining information on running processes in general depends on the operating system you are using.  The Python standard library does not contain a platform-independent way of obtaining this information.  There are, however, third-party libraries for this purpose, e.g. [psutil](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/).

Comment: thank you for your answer. Ive checked your link, and I see that we can easily check if the app has been launched. However, how do I get the time "value" (amount of time since the process was opened). Thanks in advance

Comment: @mouse_wheel As shown in the documentation we linked, you can use `process.create_time()` to obtain the time the proces was created.  (That is, provided you don't use Windows, but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt here.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I would try something using Task Manager data, probably using `subprocess.check_output(ps)`(for me that looks good), but you can the `[psutil][1]` library.

Tell us what you did later :)